# Is it possible to link to specific date on a public Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I help run a small single day [BarCamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BarCamp)-style unconference event, and we publish our session schedule (as it evolves) on a public Google Calendar. We would like to create a short link (eg. http://cal.ourevent.com) to the single day of the event on our calendar, so that attendees can check in on the schedule to decide which session to go to next, or see if anything new has been posted since the last time they checked.

I know how to add a sub-domain, what I need to figure out is what URL to redirect to for the calendar. I need to link directly to the day of the event; not the current day. I have seen [how to link to a single event](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html), but that's also not what I need. We'll have a few dozen events on the calendar on the day of the conference, and they all need to be displayed.

If at all possible, I would prefer for it to show a mobile interface when viewed from a mobile device, and the normal/expected interface when viewed from a non-mobile browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So far, the best solution we've come up with is to get the Embed code and create a page that embeds an iFrame of the appropriate size, detecting mobile browsers and adjusting the viewport accordingly.

Instead of using the **DAY** mode (which still looks like poo on mobile browsers), we've figured out how to switch to **Agenda** mode:

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showNav=0&showPrint=0&showCalendars=0&mode=AGENDA&wkst=1&src={our_calendar_id}&dates=yyyymmdd%2Fyyyymmdd
```

Here it is: http://cal.higheredphilly.com/ -- should be fairly viewable on at least Android and iOS phones. iPad and non-mobile devices get no viewport adjustment and the iframe should fill the page.

Scratch that last bit. Instead of using an iFrame, when you're not on a mobile browser we've decided to just redirect straight to the day-view calendar. That way there's no issues with iframe size rendering on IE/etc.

Answer (score 4):

I know this works for private calendars.

Try: https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=mc&date=20081101

Comment: This url format does limit the scope of the calendar to a single day, which is another step in the right direction; but it doesn't switch to the mobile interface when on mobile browsers (so it still looks like poo.) Any idea how to get that working?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. However, passing a single DATE parameter isn't enough. The URL needs a Date Range. The following parameters worked perfectly for me to get a Week view directly to a certain date:

```
?tab=mc&mode=week&dates=20160509/20160512
```

Comment: This Date Range is exactly what I needed— my only question now is where did you find this documented?

Answer (score 2):

adding below to url sets date and view

=mc&date=20130527      for example will jump to may 27th 2013

&mode=month            for example will default to month view.  day & week also work.

Comment: How is this different than @Scott's [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3460/354)?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is link to this:

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/week/2021/12/8

Just change the last values to link to another date.
Also, you can change the "week" to day or month to change how much of the calendar is shown.

*a bit late for your case, but others might find it useful.*

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in getting today's calendar to display in `mode=DAY` (instead of `mode=AGENDA`) using only URL parameters, no server or client-side code. Here's what I use:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=****&mode=DAY&dates=20090401/20401231
```

By setting the values for `dates` to range from any past date to any future date. I set the dates to far in the past through far into the future so I don't have to change them frequently (I'm using this for an in-office digital signage setup).